# grab more info before preg_replace

Tags: php

I have a script that replaces all BBCODES in comments to HTML.

I have managed to convert all the simple codes except the username code `[user="max"]` because I need to grab more user information such as user reputation & user online status from the database.

```
  $bbextended = array(
    "/\[url](.*?)\[\/url]/i" => "<a href=\"http://$1\" title=\"$1\">$1</a>",
    "/\[user=(.*?)\]/i" => "<div class=\"user\"> <a href=\"/user/$1\" title=\"$1\">$1</a><span> $USER REPUTATION </span></div>",
  );

  foreach($bbextended as $match=>$replacement){
    $bbtext = preg_replace($match, $replacement, $bbtext);
  }
```

Since `preg_replace` replaces matches inside it's function, I cannot get the username to grab other user information from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find you can massively expand your BBCode library if you use `preg_replace_callback`.

Example:

```
$bbextended = array(
  "/\[url](.*?)\[\/url]/i" => "<a href=\"http://$1\" title=\"$1\">$1</a>",
  "/\[user=(.*?)\][\/url]/i" => function($m) {
    $foo = "bar";
    return "<div class=\"user\" <a href=\"/user/".$m[1]."\" title=\"".$m[1]."\">"
                        .$m[1]."</a><span> ".$foo." </span></div>";
  }
);

foreach($bbextended as $match=>$replacement){
  if( is_callable($replacement)) {
    $bbtext = preg_replace_callback($match, $replacement, $bbtext);
  }
  else {
    $bbtext = preg_replace($match, $replacement, $bbtext);
  }
}
```